# Sign in form is always performing user doesn't exist condtion even when i enter right email and password in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am submitting this form in PHP. It has two fields user name and user password.

```
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>E-mail: &nbsp;</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="e_mail_address" name="email" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="e_passwd">
      <label>Password: &nbsp;</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="password" id="passwd" name="pass"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <button type="submit" id="sign_in_btn" name="sign_in_btn"></button>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my page i am submitting my form to. I am writing the area which is causing problem.

```
$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string($user_email);
$user_password = mysql_real_escape_string($user_password);
$query = "SELECT * from user WHERE user_email='$user_email' AND user_password='$user_password'";
$retrieve = new retrieve();
$hold = $retrieve->getdata($query);
if (!$holder) {

  echo "user does not exist";
} else {
  if ($hold['user_active'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['login'] == true;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user_email;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $user_password;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $hold['user_name'];
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $hold['user_id'];
    header("Location:index.php");
  } else if ($hold['user_active'] == 0) {
    echo "you have to activate your account first by clicking the link we have sent you on your email";
  }
}
```

Problem is whenever i am trying to sign in even with my right credentials it is always performing the same condition that user does not exist. And another error it shows is that undefined variable $hold.
What could be the problem here. For explaining here is my main part of retrieve class. it is getdata function that i have in my retieve class.

```
$this->stmnt = $this->hold->query($query);
//$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$this->result = $this->stmnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($this->result) {
  return $this->result;
}
```

Comment: `$holder === undefined`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $hold=$retrieve->getdata($query);
    if(!$holder)
```

`$hold` is not `$holder`

Comment: is it the reason why it is not reaching to the else statement.
and is my logic right which i have written in else statement @quentin

Comment: Yes. `$holder` is always false because you haven't assigned anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$holder)  //use hold  and  not  holder
                {

                    echo "user does not exist";
                    }
```